# inititialize_mint instruction failed: invalid account data for instruction

Tags: python, solana

first and foremost, I presume that initialize_mint is the process to create a token.

I have this program written that seems to me to be ok without an issue:

```rust
use solana_program::{
    account_info::{next_account_info, AccountInfo},
    entrypoint,
    entrypoint::ProgramResult,
    pubkey::Pubkey,
    program::{invoke},
};

use spl_token::{instruction::*};

entrypoint!(process_instructions);

pub fn process_instructions(program_id: &Pubkey, accounts: &[AccountInfo], _: &[u8]) -> ProgramResult{
    let account_info_iter = &mut accounts.iter();

    let mint_account_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
    let rent_account_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;


    let mint_authority_pubkey = program_id.clone();
    let freeze_authority_pubkey = program_id.clone();
    let decimals = 0;
    let token_program_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
    invoke(
        &initialize_mint(&token_program_info.key, &mint_account_info.key,  &mint_authority_pubkey, Some(&freeze_authority_pubkey), decimals)?,
        &[mint_account_info.clone(), rent_account_info.clone(), token_program_info.clone()]
    )?;

    Ok(())
}
```

But then when I proceed to call it from the client, I am using this code: `edited to include create_account as pointed out by` `@Jon C`

```py
payer_account_meta = AccountMeta(payer_keypair.public_key, True, True)
spl_program_meta  = AccountMeta(TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, False, False)
rent_account_meta = AccountMeta(solana.sysvar.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY, False, False)
mint_keypair = Keypair.generate()
mint_account_meta = AccountMeta(mint_keypair.public_key, False, True)

create_account_params = system_program.CreateAccountParams(payer_account_meta.pubkey, mint_account_meta.pubkey, Token.get_min_balance_rent_for_exempt_for_mint(client), 82, spl_program_meta.pubkey)
client.send_transaction(Transaction().add(
    system_program.create_account(create_account_params)
), payer_keypair, mint_keypair)


accounts = [
    mint_account_meta,
    rent_account_meta,
    spl_program_meta
    ]


transaction = Transaction()
transaction.add(TransactionInstruction(
    accounts,
    program_id,
    bytes([])
))

client.send_transaction(transaction, payer_keypair)
```

running this give me the error:`even after including` `create_account` `it still gives thesame error` [image]

What is the account data I am getting wrong please?

Answer (score 1):

Very close! You need to *create* an account before *initializing* it.  You have two options:

- create the account in a separate instruction, as seen in the solana-py client: https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/f41f020938d1fb257142f18608bcb884adb54479/src/spl/token/core.py#L114
- create the account from within your program, using a cross-program invocation, similar to https://solanacookbook.com/references/programs.html#create-a-program-derived-address but using `invoke` instead of `invoke_signed`, and without the program-derived address / seeds

Note that this all requires a signature from the mint keypair.

Edit post modification:

It looks like you're still generating a new keypair in `mint_account_meta` instead of using `mint_keypair`, so instead of `Keypair.generate()`, try:

```
mint_account_meta = AccountMeta(mint_keypair.public_key, False, True)
```

Comment: I was able to find that I needed to create_account, from `solana_cookbook` but unfortunately I still get thesame error. 

I was able to verify that it was created from https://explorer.solana.com/address/8rS9FgJYbzpL53FfReKQJFQQf7X9tR2GL7oV61Df47b9?cluster=devnet

So I am still inclined to believe that it might be that I am using the wrong order of accounts, or I still need to do another thing on another account.

Any input to that will be much appreciated.

Comment: I'll edit my answer for the next bit

Comment: oops, My bad.

I forgot to include that particular fix in my post here. but even with it, I get thesame Error

Comment: I ran the Token.create_mint from client and it worked just fine, so my guess is that the problem is probably in the accounts I am sending, maybe I need to send other accounts like freeze_authority, mint_authority, etc., if so, then I have no idea the order to use.